# dump dockerized postgres in a local file c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, azure-functions, pg-dump

Hi I am trying to dump a postgres db in a docker. The script I use on powershell is :

`docker exec -t timescaledb pg_dumpall -c -U postgres  > ..\dump_timescales\dump_prova.sql`

It work as expected. I am not able to figure it out how to run it in c#.
I tried the following:

```
internal static bool dumpTdb(DateTime time)
        {
            
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = $"/C  docker exec -t timescaledb pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > ..\\dump_timescales\\dump_prova_{time}.sql";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I get no error however no file is dumped.
What am I missing?
Which is the best practice to dump a db from c#?

Additional info: I am running this function from a Time Triggered Azure function.

Answer (score 0):

`process.Start` - as the name implies - *starts* a process. If you exit your program after calling `dumpTdb`, then all child processes, including your dump process, will be killed.

Call `process.WaitForExit()` to wait for the dump to finish like this

```
internal static bool dumpTdb(DateTime time)
        {
            
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = $"/C  docker exec -t timescaledb pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > ..\\dump_timescales\\dump_prova_{time}.sql";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: I figured out that the problem was the path of the local files. I am using VS and the debug path does not match with the directory the project is in. In addition, the time string was not good because it contained "/" that gave error finding the right path. 
I surely add the wait for exit by the way, so thanks a lot !